# woocommerce product image not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have BIG problem and can't solve it... I installed WooCommerce plugin to my website on Wordpress and when i change my code to my preferences and go sleep everything working, but after a week on products page image product not working :( I do not know what it could be because on this week everythink working and suddenly prodtucts image(and quanity) stop working :(

When I check with debugger Chrome if there are photos I find it, but with style "display:none", and when i change to "display:block" and photo is "working" then script to sweet show this image not working :(

Thank's for the help

P.s. sory, my english is bad but I hope you understand :)

Comment: What theme are you using? Is it WooCommerce compatible?

Comment: yes, it is 123Ecology 1.0.2, client give me this themes, and when i install WooCommerce everything working :/

Comment: @Lukasz The only thing that comes to mind is maybe there was an update to the theme that broke the Woocommerce products. You could try and find which file displays the products in the theme and check the code there. It, unfortunately, will be a matter of going from file to file and finding out what's causing the issue.